# Running SALib with pre - run simulation

Tags: dataframe, analysis

I would like to use SALib for sensitivity analysis, using the sobol method.
As i read in tutorials, you must firstly generate a sample from your input vector (in my case 7 inputs), the values of which, must be then evaluated by your model (1 output).

However, in my situation i have already run my model and have the out stored in a data frame (approx 50000 entries).

Q1. Does anyone have experience with running the library in a situation a stated above? (pre-run results already stored)

alternatively

How to create a suitable sample, from a pre - run set of model runs, for sobol sensitivity analysis

Q2. Any documentation on the library, as far as suitability of each method is concerned?

Comment: It depends on how your sample was generated. SALib uses a very specific sampling pattern for the calculation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286191/python-sensitivity-analysis-from-measured-data-with-salib-toolbox/48226907#48226907). If your initial sample was from Latin hypercube or something similar it will likely not work. You could investigate fitting a surrogate model to the points you sampled and obtaining your indices that way.