# Using saltelli.sample, from SALIb, with variables that have integer values

Tags: python

I want to create a Saltelli sample for a Sobol analysis. For this I'm using the [SALib package](https://salib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#an-example).

For creating the sample, one needs to do something like this:

```py
from SALib.sample import saltelli
problem = {
    'num_vars': 3,
    'names': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'],
    'bounds': [[-3, 10],
               [-3.14159265359, 3.14159265359],
               [-3.14159265359, 3.14159265359]]
}
```

Where "num_vars" is the number of variables which bounds are given in "bounds".

I want the values for the variable x1 to be all integers, but I keep getting real numbers. Is there a way to specify the type when running saltelli.sample.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to specify integers instead of floats. The sampling method generates floats on (0,1) using the Sobol' sequence and then multiplies those by the bounds.

A different approach would be to modify the generated samples. For instance, you could modify the first bounds to `[-3.5,10.5]` and then round the column to make integer values that would be uniformly distributed on the integers between -3 and 10. You can then use the rounded value in future calculations without a problem because the whole column is transformed using the same method.

```
problem = {
    'num_vars': 3,
    'names': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'],
    'bounds': [[-3.5, 10.5],
               [-3.14159265359, 3.14159265359],
               [-3.14159265359, 3.14159265359]]
}
```

Comment: @user3838738, I'm happy to provide a solution. Please accept and/or upvote it

Comment: I have a follow-up question on the issue above. Your answer did solve neatly the issue, however another issue appears if one wishes to do a Sobol analysis. Briefly, the Sobol analysis requires something like this: Si = sobol.analyze(problem, Y). The issue here is that "problem" will generate a grid of real numbers, not integers, so the Sobol analysis could be linking outputs that were generated with inputs that are integers to inputs that are real numbers.  I'm not sure how to solve this, given that sobol.analyze requires using the "problem" dictionary.

Comment: The algorithm in sobol.analyze(problem, Y) does not create or use another real sample like from saltelli.sample. The "problem" is only needed for the "num_vars" and "names" entries for your example. "num_vars" specifies how the sampling matrices were generated (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47286191/python-sensitivity-analysis-from-measured-data-with-salib-toolbox/48226907#48226907). "names" labels the calculated output. No second sampling of real values occurs.